# Filtering cells from values in metadata

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

I metadata slot of Seurat object I have mapping score of each cell to a reference PBMC data like

```
pbmc <- subset(object, subset = object@meta.data$mapping.score > 0.5)
Error in FetchData(object = object, vars = unique(x = expr.char[vars.use]),  : 
  None of the requested variables were found: 
> 
> 
>
```

I want to only keep cells with mapping score > 0.5

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
your_new_object <- subset(your_object, subset = mapping.score > 0.5)
```